# Do UART RX interrupts require support from the transmitter?

Tags: microcontroller, uart, serial, interrupts, atmel

I'm trying to understand why I am seeing RX interrupts when tying RX to TX of my SAMR34 but not when I connect it to the transmitting device.  The transmitting device notes the following restrictions:

`Serial hardware flow controls (RTS/CTS and DTR/DSR) are not used and will be ignored.  In addition, the receiver must not use software flow control (XON/XOFF)`

I do see data from the transmitter when I poll. Does interrupt driven UART require support from the transmitter?  Should I switch to DMA to resolve this issue?  Here is my setup

[image]

Comment: please copy the code into the question and indent it. How many bytes do SAMR34 send and how many do the _transmitter_ send?

Comment: I used a different SAM device 6 years ago but had no problems with Rx interrupts. I know Tx was nasty but I can't remember why.

Answer (score 0):

To state the obvious, no, there is no "support" in the transmitter that is required for an RX interrupt on the receiver side. If you get the transmitter data by polling, the RX interrupt should fire, provided you enable it correctly.